Can a publication license for one figure be different than the whole article's license?
A funder requires a scholar to publish their paper with a CC-BY license.
However, the paper includes a figure which is taken from another source and which is accompanied with a CC-BY-NC-SA license.
Is it conventional, or perhaps: legally possible, that the figure's license deviates from the license for the rest of the article?

Related: Can I include images licensed CC BY-NC 4.0 in a conference paper?

The general advice is to exclude the image in question from the CC-BY license, as per https://creativecommons.org/faq/#may-i-apply-a-cc-license-to-my-work-if-it-incorporates-material-used-under-fair-use-or-another-exception-or-limitation-to-copyright

In general you can reproduce a figure already published elsewhere in a new paper, if you have separate permission or if the figure's license allows it.
In that particular case, with the figure under CC-BY-NC-SA license, the non-commercial clause may be problematic if you intend to publish the new paper with a commercial publisher. That could be interpreted as commercial use of the figure, which would not be allowed by its license. It would be best to check the planned figure use with the publisher of the new paper: they are taking the risk and they should have staff to check whether this use of the figure would be allowed.

I think you misunderstand NC. The authors aren't monetizing the work by including the figure.

@Buffy but maybe the publisher does, for example by putting advertisements next to the online article.

In any case, I'm not saying that this violates NC, I'm saying that one should check with the publisher whether this licence clause is ok for them or not.

@silvado I agree about monetize and would also  add or by charging people to view the article :/

Anyway, there are a lot of things that CC-BY allows but CC-BY-NC-SA don't allow, and therefore the aren't compatible.

If you include a licensed figure in a publication you don't alter the license of that figure, even if the overall publication has a less restrictive license. Users of your work will need to adhere to the license given on the figure, just as you do. So, yes, different parts of a given publication can have different licenses. Only the copyright holder can give or alter a license and can only give a less restrictive one as a user might already hold a permissive license.
There is a lot of discussion about the meaning of NC in CC licenses. But a paper by an academic is not likely infringing as the author's purpose isn't to monetize the figure included but to extend some scholarly ideas. Authors are seldom compensated. A book might be a different matter. And publishers, especially of books, might both give advice and seek a less restrictive license from authors for some things.
There is, however, one 2017 court case that seems to imply that publishers can publish such a work (FedEx case). See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_NonCommercial_license#Commentary. Note that this is a US perspective and that copyright law varies in some places. (NOTE: IANAL)
And even CC itself seems a bit unsure about the exact meaning of NC. There is a (long) report on this issue (PDF), at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Defining_noncommercial_Creative_Commons_2009.pdf

I doubt the FedEx case is generally applicable to publishers. A publisher publishing a document containing material licensed under CC-BY-NC behind a paywall takes a much more active role in using and benefiting from the material than FedEx did for simply providing a copying service. However, if the document is published under a CC-BY license, perhaps the publisher would be viewed as acting as an intermediary providing a publishing service, and be in a position similar to FedEx in that case. But I'm just speculating.

Clearly the FedEx case doesn't apply to a publisher. FedEx was found to be just a third party printing pages in behalf of a reuser, but a publisher is not just printing the article (and its figure) on behalf of the author.

Both the NC (non commercial) and the SA (share alike) clauses are problematic.
You are required to publish your article under CC-BY license. Therefore, you will be granting anybody to print and sell, modify the article with the only requirement to attribute the authors of the works (which would include the authors of the image), and even to republish it (after modifying it or not) under a different license as long as it keeps the requirement of attributing the authors. However, the image can only be distributed under CC-BY-NC-SA, which doesn't allow to sell the product and requires that any distribution would be made under the same license.
Therefore, you can't include a CC-BY-NC-SA image in an article and release the whole as CC-BY.
However, you could:

Release the article under CC-BY except for the image. That is, reusers can sell the article and republish it under a different license if they don't include the image. Probably this doesn't fulfil your founder's requirements and it may be complex to implement (although this is what Wikipedia does with some images with incompatible licenses).
Justify that the use of the image falls under fair use or any other exception of copyright. I don't think you have a strong case here but that could be an strong argument in some cases, specially if the next point is not appropriate.
Figures have copyright but ideas and information don't. You can make another figure with the same information, as long as you don't copy any of the creative elements of the figure and you cite the source of the information. In a scientific paper, creative elements usually don't matter much, so often it's perfectly possible to make a different graph to show the same values without copying the choices of linetype, color, axis, and so.
You can contact the authors to give permission to publish that particular image under CC-BY license. Since academics tend to want citations, visibility and recognition, they may agree.

